# jQuery plugin Cross Slide and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

I am using the jQuery plugin [Cross Slide](http://www.gruppo4.com/~tobia/cross-slide.shtml). My page is working fine in Chrome and Firefox. But in Internet Explorer 7, I get:

> Debug error as Object expected on line 1: 
>    
>      $(document).ready(function() { 
>           $('#image').crossSlide({sleep:4,fade:1},[{src:'images/1.jpg'},{src:'images/2.jpg'}]); 
>       });

How can I fix the bug for Internet Explorer 8 and Internet Explorer 7?

Comment: Looks like the crossSlide plugin - http://www.gruppo4.com/~tobia/cross-slide.shtml

Comment: If you could provide the whole page's source, that would be best...

Comment: do you have any other jquery code within the ready function so you can test it without the crossslide line and see if there is just and error in your page and not in that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you provide more code or even better, a working page that reproduces the problem? That little piece of code looks fine so far...

By the way, the "on line 1" tells you absolutely nothing in IE, don't trust it.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, you just have to delete the comma after the last picture you point to. This should work in IE.

Greets

Comment: This needs to be set as the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try with companion.js. It points you to the JavaScript line that has the problem instead of the default line 1. Moreover, try with unpacked JavaScript code so that you know what is wrong.